# how to capture DHCP packets in wireshark

Tags: dhcp, wireshark, packet-analysis

Hy!

I want to capture DHCP packets in Wireshark but I did not receive any. Not my filter wrong, I don't get any. So I think I can't trigger the DHCP communications.

my filters:

dhcp

bootp

udp.port == 68

bootp.option.type == 53

I tried these:

1.) ipconfig /release & renew

2.)on my router I put into exclusion the IP address and I get a new but I did not capture any DHCP packet.

What I need to do to capture any packet and trigger the DHCP Discovery/offer/request/ack

Thanks

Comment: You really want to do the capture on the DHCP server, not the DHCP client, which is not configured.

Comment: You may be capturing on the wrong interface

Comment: After I restarted the program it was good. Maybe the problem was It ran for 11 hours and something stuck. 

You can capture DHCP on the client too not just on the server.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you're running Wireshark on Linux, do you have proper permission? E.g. sudo

Second, are you on the right network interfaces? Refer to the image, notice that there are a few interfaces on it. Some of them have network activities, while the others are not. You don't want to capture the one with no activities as it will bring you nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After I restarted the program it was good. Maybe the problem was It ran for 11 hours and something stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Capture logs in wireshark by neither way by taking TCP dump on client  computer with source as client ip address and destination as DHCP server ip address . Please trigger DHCP traffic from client by enable DHCP options on network adapter setting so that DHCP dora process start and traffic is capture on TCP dump

Later open this TCP dump pcap file in wireshark tool for clear understanding and analysis.